# KC - space and FDS - property

Tags: general-topology, filters

I saw a question that was asked by " Maryam " she asked:
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a $T_1$ topological space. Let $D=\{d_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a countably infinite closed discrete subspace of $X$. Fix $p\in X$ and let $F\in\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ be an ultrafilter and define a new topology $σ$ on $X$:

$$\sigma=\{U\in\tau∶p\notin U\}\cup\big\{U\in\tau:p\in U\text{ and }\{n\in\omega:d_n\in U\}\in F\big\}$$

Do we have $(X,\sigma)$ a $T_1$ space, and strict containment $\sigma\subsetneqq\tau$? We have for every $B\subseteq X$ that $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(B)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_\tau(B)\cup\{p\}$. Can we say that for every non-closed $A$, $p\in\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A)$?

But it was answered by " Daniel - Fischer ". He said that the second answer is false.

I previously saw its proof and now, I show lemma $9$ from the article ‘space in which compact subsets are closed and the lattice of  - topology on a set’ by Alas. he proved:

> **Lemma 9:** if $(X,\tau)$ is a countable  non-compact $KC$–space with the $FDS$ property, then $X$ can be condensed onto a weaker $KC$–space.
>
> **Proof:**  Since $X$ is not countably compact, there is some countably infinite closed discrete subspace $D = \{d_n:n\in\omega\}\subseteq X$. Fix $p\in X$ and $\mathscr{F}\in\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ and  define  a new topology $\sigma$ on $X$ as follows:
>
> $$σ = \{U\in\tau∶p \notin U\}\cup \big\{U\in\tau : p \in U\text{ and }\{n \in\omega:d_n\in U\}\in\mathscr{F}\big\}$$
>
> Clearly $(X,\sigma)$ is a $T_1$–space, and $\sigma\subseteq\tau$ and for each $B\subseteq X$, $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(B)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_\tau(B)\cup\{p\}$. We show that is a $KC$–space. To this end, suppose to the contrary that $A$ is a non-closed compact subspace of $(X,\sigma)$. Obviously $p\in\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A)$  and there are two cases to consider:
>
> 1. If $p \notin A$, then $A_\sigma = A_\tau$ and so $A$ is compact and hence closed in $(X,\tau)$. Thus there is some $U\in\tau$ such that $p\in U$ and $U\cap A = \varnothing$. If $\{n\in\omega :d_n\in A\}\notin\mathscr{F}$, then $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in D\setminus A\}\in \mathscr{F}$ and for each $t\in D\setminus A$ we can choose $U_t$ such that $t\in U_t$ and $U_t\cap A = \varnothing$. Then $p\in U\cup\bigcup\{U_t:t \in D\setminus A\}\in\sigma$, contradicting the fact that $p\in\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A)$. Thus $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in A\}\in\mathscr{F}$, and then there is some infinite set $S\subseteq A \cap D$ such that $S \notin\mathscr{F}$ and $S$ is then an infinite closed discrete  subset of $A$ in $(X,\sigma)$, implying that $(A,\sigma_A)$ is not compact.
> 2. If $p\in A$, then $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A) = \operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)$. if $A$ is not closed in $(X,\tau)$, then $A$ is not compact (thus not countably compact) in $(X,\tau)$, and so there is an infinite discrete subset $C\subseteq A$  which  is closed  in $(A,\tau_A)$. However, $C$ is not closed in $(A,\sigma_A)$, and so $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(C)\cap A  = C \cup \{p\}$. This implies that $\{n \in\omega:d_n\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau(C)\}\in\mathscr{F}$. Since $(X,\tau)$ has the $FDS$–property, there is some infinite subset $B\subseteq A$  with only a finite number of accumulation points in $X$. Thus $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau(B)\}\notin\mathscr{F}$, which implies that $B$ is closed and discrete in $(A,\sigma_A)$, implying in its turn that $A$ is not compact in $(X,\sigma)$.

So, I have question:

1. Why in the first paragraph $p\in\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A)$?
2. Why in the last line in part (1), $S\notin\mathscr{F}$ and $S$ is then an infinite closed discrete subset of $A$ in $(X,\sigma)$, implying that $(A,\sigma_A)$ is not compact?
3. Why in the part (2), $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(C)\cap A  = C \cup\{p\}$ implies that $\{n \in\omega:d_n\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau(C)\}\in\mathscr{F}$?

---

the $FDS$-property means:

the space $X$ has the $FDS$-property if whenever $A\subseteq X$ is infinite, there is an infinite subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $B$ has only a finite number of accumulation  points in $X$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KC - space , FDS - property](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454319/kc-space-fds-property)

Comment: You made a few typos and omitted a few things in transcribing the proof of Lemma $9$; please check to see whether I restored them correctly.

Comment: @StefanH.: There are, I think, three copies of this question; this is the first one that I came across, so it’s the one that I edited into more readable form. Let’s use it as the ‘real’ question and make the others duplicates (assuming that this gets an upvoted answer).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Of course two questions shouldn't be duplicates of each other. I will retract the close vote.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $x\in X\setminus\{p\}$; then the $\sigma$-nbhds of $x$ are the $\tau$-nbhds of $x$, so $x\in\cl_\sigma A$ iff $x\in\cl_\tau A$. Suppose that $p\notin\cl_\sigma A$; then $p\notin\cl_\tau A$, so $\cl_\sigma A=\cl_\tau A$. Moreover, $p\notin A$, so $A_\sigma=A_\tau$, and since $A$ is compact in $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$, it must be compact in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ as well. $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is $KC$, so $A$ is closed in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$. But then $A$ must be closed in $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$ as well, since $p\notin\cl_\sigma A$, and for each $x\in X\setminus\{p\}$ we have $x\in\cl_\sigma A$ iff $x\in\cl_\tau A$. This contradiction shows that $p\in\cl_\sigma A$.
2. Let $F=\{n\in\omega:d_n\in A\}\in\mathscr{F}$, and we know that $F\in\mathscr{F}$. Let $\{F_0,F_1\}$ be a partition of $F$ into two infinite subsets; it’s a basic property of ultrafilters that exactly one of $F_0$ and $F_1$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$. Without loss of generality assume that $F_1\in\mathscr{F}$, and let $S=\{d_n:n\in F_0\}$. Then $S$ is an infinite subset of $A\cap D$, and $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in S\}=F_0\notin\mathscr{F}$. (The paper has a small error here: it’s $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in S\}$ that is not in $\mathscr{F}$, not $S$ itself.) $A_\sigma=A_\tau$, and $A\cap D$ is closed and discrete in $X\setminus\{p\}$ with respect to $\tau$, so $A\cap D$ is closed and discrete in $X\setminus\{p\}$ with respect to $\sigma$ as well. It follows that $S$ is closed and discrete in $X\setminus\{p\}$ with respect to $\sigma$. To show that $S$ is closed and discrete in $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$, we need only show that $p\notin\cl_\sigma S$. Let $U=X\setminus\{d_n:n\in F_0\}$; $D$ is closed and discrete in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, so every subset of $D$ is closed in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, and therefore $U\in\tau$. Moreover, $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in U\}=\omega\setminus F_0\in\mathscr{F}$, so $U\in\sigma$ as well. Thus, $U$ is a $\sigma$-nbhd of $p$, and clearly $U\cap S=\varnothing$, so $p\notin\cl_\sigma S$, and $S$ is closed and discrete in $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$. Of course this means that $A$ contains a closed, discrete subset with respect to $\sigma$ and therefore cannot be compact.
3. If $(\cl_\sigma C)\cap A=C\cup\{p\}$, then in particular $p\in\cl_\sigma C$. Let $U=X\setminus\cl_\tau C$; clearly $U\in\tau$. If $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in\cl_\tau C\}\notin\mathscr{F}$, then $\{n\in\omega:d_n\in U\}=\{n\in\omega:d_n\notin\cl_\tau C\}\in\mathscr{F}$. This means that if $p\in U$, then $U$ is a $\sigma$-nbhd of $p$ disjoint from $C$, contradicting the hypothesis that $p\in\cl_\sigma C$. Thus, we need only show that $p\in U$, i.e., that $p\notin\cl_\tau C$. But this is clear: $C$ is closed in $\langle A,\tau_A\rangle$, and $p\in A$, so $p$ has a $\tau$-nbhd disjoint from $C$. (It’s clear that $p\notin C$: if $p$ were in $C$, then $C$, being closed in $\langle A,\tau_A\rangle$, would also be closed in $\langle A,\sigma_A\rangle$, and it’s not.)